# Como passar duas variáveis em um steless com Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Fala pessoal!
Estou começando no flutter!
Conseguem me dar uma luz ai?
Pego o 'snapshot' de outra tela com o Navigator.of(context).push e nesta tela ProdutoScreen preciso pegar o json dos produtos com a apiProdutos, porém estou perdido aqui, na outra tela que eu não pegava nada de outra tela funcionou usando o esquema abaixo

```
class CategoriaTile extends StatelessWidget {

  final CategoryListModel snapshot;

  CategoriaTile(this.snapshot);
```

Porem nesta tela como tenho que declarar o snapshot e os dados da apiProduto, o apiProduto esta vindo como null, como posso declarar essas duas variaveis?

Tentei desta forma, porem sem sucesso

```
class ProdutoScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  final CategoryListModel snapshot;

  ListaProdutoData apiProduto;

  ProdutoScreen(this.snapshot){
    apiProduto = ListaProdutoData();
  }
```

Comment: O que é um "steless"?? E não entendi bem sua dúvida,você quer passar dois parâmetros no constructor? Basta fazer `SuaClasse(this.snapshot, this.apiproduto)` e declare a `apiProduto` como FINAL.

Comment: Fiz assim:
```
  final CategoryListModel snapshot;

  ListaProdutoData apiProduto;

  ProdutoScreen(this.snapshot, this.apiProduto);
```
Da erro na outra tela.
```
Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder:
                          (context)=>ProdutoScreen(snapshot))
                  );
```
```
Compiler message:
lib/tiles/categoria_tile.dart:25:51: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
                          (context)=>ProdutoScreen(snapshot))
```

Comment: Era um problema no json, estava botando a classificação errada, deu certo a sua dica! Obg Matheus!